# Infinite-scroll document in Pages

Tags: pages, formatting

How can I create an infinite-scroll document workspace with no page breaks in Pages (like "Web Layout" in Microsoft Word)?

Microsoft Word has options for "Print Layout" and "Web Layout," the former of which has page breaks and the latter is a continuous scroll. Is there a way to set up or convert a document in Pages to have a continuous scroll with no hard-formatted page breaks?

[image: A page break in Pages]

Comment: I don't think so. Pages, as the name suggests, is about content on a defined area. What are you trying to create, exactly? A web page? Word has web view because you can save content as a web document. You can't create web pages in Pages.

Comment: @benwiggy Yeah, that's what I thought. Trying to create a document (not destined to be printed) with embedded tables, and Pages will automatically push a row down below the next page break to make it fit with no indication that the previous row isn't the end of the table. Much more of 'an inconvenience' than a major issue, but it would be nice to do this project in Pages instead of in Word, which is missing Pages' other very useful features. Thank you for the response!

Comment: If it's mostly tables with a bit of formatting, you might find Numbers is more suitable.